# Created a new column with some rules in R

Tags: r

The data I have contain three variables with three unique IDs and each has multiple records. See below

```
ID <- c(rep(1,7), rep(2,6), rep(3,5))
t <- c(seq(1,7), seq(1,6), seq(1,5))
y <- c(rep(6,7), rep(1,6), rep(6,5))
z <- c(5,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,4,2,1,0,1)
dat1 <- data.frame(ID, t, y, z)
```

I need to create a new column (let's call it updated_y0) with the following rules:

1. for each ID i = 1,2,3 and each record j, the updated_y0(i,1) (i.e., the first record for each ID ordered by t) = y(i,1).
2. updated_y0(i,j) with j>1 (i.e., started from the second record) = updated_y0(i,j-1) - z(i,j-1) (the difference of previous rows)

For example, for ID=1,

- updated_y0(1,1) = y(1,1) = 6,
- updated_y0(1,2) = updated_y0(1,1) - z(1,1) = 6-5 = 1,
- updated_y0(1,3) = updated_y0(1,2) - z(1,2) = 1-0 = 1...

The new data (dat2) is

```
    ID <- c(rep(1,7), rep(2,6), rep(3,5))
    t <- c(seq(1,7), seq(1,6), seq(1,5))
    y <- c(rep(6,7), rep(1,6), rep(6,5))
    z <- c(5,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,4,2,1,0,1)
  updated_y0 <- c(6,1,1,1,1,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,6,2,0,-1,-2)

dat2 <- data.frame(ID, t, y, z, updated_y0)
```

Comment: Maybe I'm not understanding, but for part 2, did you mean `updated_y0(1,2) = updated_y0(1,1) - z(1,1)`? rather than just `updated_y0(1,2) = y(1,1) - z(1,1)`

Comment: yes. this means that for each id and starting in the second row the updated_y0 is the difference between the previous y and z. thanks

Comment: yea, my question is are you wanting it to be `y-z` or `previous_y0 - z`.  The example you provided, the `updated_y0(1,3)` does not have a `1 - 0` above it.

Comment: sorry, you are right. it should be the previous_y0 - z.

Comment: i updated the updated_y0 values in my questions.

Comment: Updated my answer now too...should work for you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work, although I do hate using `for` loops.  First we identify all first records for each `ID` (all others will be marked `NA`):

```
library(dplyr)

dat2 <- dat1 %>% 
  group_by(ID) %>% 
  mutate(updated_y0 = ifelse(t == 1,
                            y,
                            NA))
```

Now we use a `for` loop to to replace just the `NAs`

```
for(i in 1:nrow(dat2)){
  dat2$updated_y0[i] <- ifelse(is.na(dat2$updated_y0[i]),
                               dat2$updated_y0[i-1] - dat2$z[i-1],
                               dat2$updated_y0[i])
    }

dat2
```

---

For the example of the lagging `y-z` option, you can use the `dplyr` option fairly straightforward:

```
dat1 %>% 
  group_by(ID) %>% 
  mutate(updated_y0 = ifelse(t == 1,
                            y,
                            lag(y - z)))
```

The `ifelse` gives the current `y` value as long as it is the first record (`t`).  If it is not the second record for the `ID`, then it calculates the `y-z` based on the row above it (`dplyr::lag`).